# Repeating of cells when adding new posts on social media project in Swift 3

Tags: uitableview, swift3

I have a UITableViewCell and there are labels connected to outlets and buttons connected to actions. I am using Firebase for the data storage. Its some type of social media project. But when I add new post/cell ,it reloads the table but repeats by doubling the previous posts.How can I fix this error in Swift 3?

Comment: I think data in your **posts** array is getting added twice when you reload the table, try printing the array & debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are observing for `value`, so you will get all the child data from `Firebase` every time it is changed. So remove all objects from array or initialized it as empty array inside the `completionHandler` of `observe`.

```
DataService.ds.REF_POSTS.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
    if let snapshot = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] {

        self.posts = [] //Initialize as empty array

        for snap in snapshot {
            print("SNAP: \(snap)")

            if let postDict = snap.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {

                let key = snap.key
                let post = Post(postKey: key, postData: postDict)
                //self.posts.append(post)

                self.posts.insert(post, at: 0)

                //data.insert("A", at: 0)

            }
        }
    }
    self.tableView.reloadData()
})
```